# Advice for understanding Stan machine learning code

Tags: matlab, stan

I need help trying to understand the following Stan code. I am good with Matlab, but have my problems with this code I found (see below).

First I don’t understand what exactly `vector[K] u[I]` means. Is this a Kx1 vector, a Ix1 vector or a KxI matrix? (they write something about a latent feature vector ui(vj) of dimension K = 4, but I don't understand what that means).

Then I don't quite understand what exactly `normal(0,sigma_0)` and `cauchy(u[i]'*v[j],lambda)` does. I mean, what is the output here? When I use the “normpdf” function in MATLAB, I need an additional input x at which to evaluate the distribution. So why is that missing here and what does that mean for the output?

And lastly, K is just used in the parameters section, but then not again in any for-loop, so why is the K even necessary?

Thanks in advance for any help, it is greatly appreciated!

```
data {
    int<lower=0> I;
    int<lower=0> J;
    int<lower=0> K;
    real ln_gamma[I,J];
    real<lower=0> sigma_0;
    real<lower=0> lambda;
}
parameters {
    vector[K] u[I];
    vector[K] v[J];
}
model {
    for (i in 1:I)
        u[i] ~ normal(0,sigma_0);
    for (j in 1:J)
        v[j] ~ normal(0,sigma_0);
    for (i in 1:I) {
        for (j in 1:J) {
            if (ln_gamma[i,j] != -99) {
                ln_gamma[i,j] ~ cauchy(u[i]’*v[j],lambda);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There are several parts to this question which makes it too broad... it reads like you need advice on the maths rather than the programming? If so, this might be better posted on [math.stackexchange.com](http://math.stackexchange.com)

Comment: My main problem is trying to understand Stan. I looked into the Stan documentation, for example for the parameters part and unfortunately they don't explain what it means, when there is something like "X[A] Y[B]". The documentation isn't very helpful for "normal" and "cauchy" as well, I just want to know what the respective output is, what exactly is written into u[i] when using normal(0,sigma_0)? And what is the purpose of K?

Comment: Then I suggest you edit your question to be framed as a specific coding issue. At the minute this question is phrased as if you want help understanding a concept for your PhD (we don't need this context), when actually you want to understand some specific Stan syntax... You may get answers as-is, but tailoring your question to something specific usually yields better results.